# Components of a bounded sequence of vectors are also bounded

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

If $\{x_k\}$ is sequence of vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ that is bounded: $\| x_k \| < D$. How to prove that its componentes are also bounded: $|x_k^{(1)}|, |x_k^{(2)}|, ... < M$ without assuming a particular norm $\| . \|$ ?

Comment: All norms in $\Bbb R^n$ are equivalent, so it doesn't matter which norm you choose. And if you don't want to use a norm, how do you make sense of "boundedness"?

Comment: The result is essentially that the given norm and the $\max$ norm are equivalent.

Comment: The essence of the result is that an arbitrary norm is continuous with respect to the $1$ or $\max$ norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use the fact that all norms in Real valued finite dimensional vector spaces are equivalent,  so you can squeeze the generic norm between any two norms you like with suitable positive constant mulutiples.   Just use the max norm for easiest proof.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\|x\| = \| \sum_k x_k e_k\| \le \sum_k |x_k| \|e_k\| \le M \|x\|_1$,
where $M= \max_k \|e_k\|$.

In particular, this shows that $\|\cdot\|$ is continuous in the (topology induced by) the $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm.

Let $m= \min_{\|x\|_1=1} \|x\|$ and note that $m>0$ (from compactness of the unit $\|x\|_1$ disk and property of norms) from which we get $\|x\|_1 \le {1 \over m}\|x\|$.

In particular, if $\|x\| < D$ then we have
$|x_k| \le \|x\|_1 \le {1 \over m} D$.